# Unable to call composer command

Tags: php, powershell, command-line, terminal

I've just installed Composer on my Windows 10 machine.

I would like to call composer just typing "composer" on the Command Line. Unfortunately, I can only call composer typing "php composer" on the Command Line. When I just type "composer" it says that "Program 'composer' failed to run".

Can somebody help me with this?

Best regards

Comment: Check this lines is uncommented in your php.ini:

extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_curl.dll

Comment: You should add php to your path environment on windows, take a look at https://www.forevolve.com/en/articles/2016/10/27/how-to-add-your-php-runtime-directory-to-your-windows-10-path-environment-variable/